# Meteor.findOne output is undefined except Mongo.ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb, reactjs, meteor

In my issue is my terminal shows some data from mongodb in my meteor Application.

The terminal screenshot is

[image: terminal console]

The above data retrive in my program

```
const mobile_number = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mobile).value.trim();

console.log(mobile_number);//output is 9646

let data = Tasks.findOne({mobile:mobile_number});

console.log(data); //output is undefined
```

How to retrive data find from "mobile" argument ? except Mongo.ObjectId using return data perfectly worked.

Comment: Can you check the output for `let data = Tasks.findOne({mobile:9646});` ?

Comment: yes.i checked .return output data . but this case       ` const mobile_number = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mobile).value.trim();` not worked ?

Comment: Basically, when you are trying to run the query, `mobile_number` value is undefined. So you have to wait for the value to be assigned to to `mobile_number` before running the query.

Comment: Thanks @Shrabanee .. i use Number(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mobile).value.trim());  . got answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Answer is change code

```
const mobile_number = Number(ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this.refs.mobile).value.trim());
```